# Iterating through a function's arguments by using a pointer to the first one

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing, c99, c11

I would like to know whether the following C code adheres to the C99 and/or C11 standard(s):

```
void foo(int bar0, int bar1, int bar2) {
    int *bars = &bar0;

    printf("0: %d\n1: %d\n2: %d\n", bars[0], bars[1], bars[2]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    foo(8, 32, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

This code snippet compiles and runs as expected when using visual studio 2013 and prints:

> 0: 8
>   1: 32
>   2: 4

Comment: Are you asking to satisfy your curiosity, or do you have a problem you think this will solve?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, since variadic arguments seem to use this technique to iterate over its arguments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, not anywhere near.

C standard does not guarantee that the function arguments are stored in consecutive memory locations (*or, any specific ordering, for that matter*). It is up to the compiler and/or the platform (*architecture*) to decide how the function arguments are passed to the function.

To add some more clarity, there is even no guarantee that the arguments which are to be passed are stored in memory (e.g., stack), at all. They can make use of the hardware registers, too (*whenever applicable*), for some *or* all the parameters, to make the operations fast. For example,

- PowerPC

  > The PowerPC architecture has a large number of registers so most functions can pass all arguments in registers for single level calls.  [...]
- MIPS

  > The most commonly used calling convention for 32 bit MIPS is the O32 ABI which passes the first four arguments to a function in the registers `$a0`-`$a3`; subsequent arguments are passed on the stack. [...]
- X86

  > The x86 architecture is used with many different calling conventions. Due to the small number of architectural registers, the x86 calling conventions mostly pass arguments on the stack, while the return value (or a pointer to it) is passed in a register.

and so on. Check the [full wiki article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

So, in your case, `bars[0]` is a *valid* access, but whether `bars[1]` and `bars[2]` are valid, depends on the underlying *environment* (platform/compiler), entirely. Best not to rely on the behavior you're expecting.

That said, just to nitpick, in case you don't intend to use the arguments (*if any*) passed to `main()` , you can simply reduce the signature to `int main(void) {`.

Comment: +1, but perhaps one should add that on modern architectures the first function parameters aren't stored in memory at all but passed through hardware registers. And perhaps also that it is not the compiler that decides, but the platform API.

Comment: @JensGustedt Sir, added a bit more info on that front. Any better now?

Answer (score 7):

No it does not adhere to any published standard. How arguments and local variables are stored, and where, is up to the compiler. What might work in one compiler might not work in another, or even on a different version of the same compiler.

The C specification doesn't even mention a stack, all it specifies are the scoping rules.

Comment: Variadic functions also seem to be part of the standard - va_start, va_end are part of the standard library, and that's exactly what these macros are doing - going over the stack parameters.

Comment: @MichaelMoser Yes, but how those macros are implemented is not in the standard. And having a stack is not a requirement for a C compiler (especially since it's not in the C specification), it's just convenient implementation detail.

Answer (score 5):

No standard supports this. It's extremely naughty.

Array indexing and pointer arithmetic is only valid for arrays. (Note a small exception: you can *read* a pointer one past an array or a scalar, but you can't *deference* it.)